# Android LinkedIn Native Application

Tags: android, linkedin-api, linkedin-j

I want to integrate LinkedIn in my Android application, all the samples I had seen is done through Android Webview. Is there way to provide username and password from my application and login to LinkedIn

Comment: Why don't you try and integrate LinkedIn Android SDK https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk

Comment: Already using LinkedIn SDK only, but it is done through WebView, I want to avoid that, want to use our own app UI.

Comment: If you are trying like, user will insert username and password in your app and it should redirect to LinkedIn app, its not possible, u can use a custom button and handle output in onActivityResult